# Change value button on click with jquery: how to refer to the button in my code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, debugging, toggle

I am trying to make a button which will change text from kilometres to miles upon click. So far after reading other answers this is my code:

```
      $("#change").on('click', function(){
      var elem = $(this);
      if (elem.value == "Change to miles") {
       elem.value = "Change to kilometres";
      } else {
        elem.value = "Change to miles";
      }
```

However it does not work, the problem seems to be the line "var elem = $(this)".
I also tried with getElementById, with no success. Could anyone help me find the bug?
My HTML code is:

```
<input type = "button" id = "change" value = 'Change to miles'> </button>
```

Comment: what's the error message?

Comment: Object Manipulator's answer worked! I changed $(this) to this.

Answer (score 1):

```js
$("#change").on('click', function() {
      var elem = $(this);
      if (elem.val() == "Change to miles") {
        elem.val("Change to kilometres");
      } else {
        elem.val("Change to miles");
      }
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" id="change" value='Change to miles' />
```

1. Close html properly.
2. Use [.val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/) to set and get data.

Answer (score 0):

You have mixed javascript and jquery. `$(this)` is jQuery element so you need to use `.val()` method for getting/setting value. Not `.value`

If you want to use `.value` you need to pick the element instance using javascript. something like this :

```js
$("#change").on('click', function() {
  var elem = document.getElementById("change");
  if (elem.value == "Change to miles") {
    elem.value = "Change to kilometres";
  } else {
    elem.value = "Change to miles";
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" id="change" value='Change to miles'/>
```

I generally use `data` attrib to identify the state of the element not the text on it, you can also use it this way :

```js
$("#change").click(function(){
  var elem = $(this);
  if(elem.data("type") === "km"){
    elem.val("Change to kilometers").data("type", "mil");
  } else if(elem.data("type") === "mil"){
    elem.val("Change to miles").data("type", "km");
  } 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type = "button" id = "change" value = 'Change to miles' data-type="km"/>
```